# How to retry downloading xml file from web once failed Android

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to make an android app which needs to download an xml file from the web when it installs in a users phone for the first time. Since its a data based application, that xml file is required to set up the database and without it the application will not work. However, when the download is successful.. everything runs fine but many times I have noticed that the download is not successful due to loss of network or other problems like connection timeout. What should i do? If the file does not download for the first time.. my database is created but is empty... is there a way to retry downloading the xml file from web.

```
try{

    URL url = new URL("http://example.com/abc.xml");
    XmlPullParserFactory factory=XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    xpp=factory.newPullParser();

    xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");
}catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
}

public InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
      try {
        return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
      }
    }
```

Comment: check whether the file is downloaded into the sd or not if no then retry to load again other wise start the application @Swathi Rawat

Comment: how should i check if the file has been completely downloaded or not..

Comment: maintain a flag variable in shared preference for maintain the status of the file whether it is downloaded or not. whenever you are launching the application then check that flag variable value.based on that you perform the downloading operation...

Comment: if the xml file downloading is fail then you may get the exception.so in exception block you assign a value to flag variable @Swati Rawat

Answer (score 0):

Check a boolean variable responses if it is true mean file download successfuly then do nothing else restart the downloading ..

Comment: can you share some code on how to retry the download... I will attach my current code..